# Is RelativeLayout.LayoutParams is a class because we have to create object for the same?

Tags: java, android

Please explain thoroughly the concept of this. I am little confused about the same though the concepts are of JAVA basics.
I am attaching the screenshot to help you understand my situation.[image]

**ButtonDetails is the object created for RelativeLayout.LayoutParams? So why do we pass two parameters in the constuctor of the object.**

Comment: What is the error Android studio is telling you?

Comment: @AntonMakov there is no error I just need understanding of this thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) is a nested class of [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#nestedclasses).

Example of nested class:

```
class OuterClass {
   ...
class NestedClass {
    ...
   }
}
```

Info on nested classes:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, like all other classes, is a class because of its declaration:

```
public static class RelativeLayout.LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams 
{

....
}
```

**RelativeLayout.LayoutParams is still a class, no meter if you create an object from it or not.**

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Why we need to send RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT two times and what data type they return? I did refer to this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html but it didn't make things very clear.

Comment: This first WRAP_CONTENT is width, and the second is height. Its like in XML ,android:layout_height="wrap_content".  You don't have to put "WRAP_CONTENT" you can put other parameters like "MATCH_PARENT" and "FILL_PARENT".

Comment: Okay this works, also passed many other required parameter. Thanks.